# Alternative for `Union` in Salesforce

Tags: soql, salesforce1-app

I have the following columns

```
uName1, uName2 ...... uName30
```

Since the name's length is long, if will be very difficult for me to read the screen using developer console and SOQL like this

```
select uName1, uName2 ...... uName30 from tbName
```

Is there anyway I can achieve the result like using `union` in SQL

```
Select uName1
Union
Select uName2
Union
...
```

P/s : export data by DataLoader into excel is not an option, I can only use the Developer Console

Comment: Are you looking to use a query union to truly combine the result-set of two or more different tables or are you more interested in the formatting it can offer? If the latter, using indentation and line breaks works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SOQL doesn't support query unions. Limiting yourself to only the Developer Console means you have no other options available to you.